# Where has gone "Online Accounts" in 15.10?

Tags: 15.10

I've just upgraded my 15.04 to 15.10. I'm now wondering where has just gone the "Online Accounts" option.

It used to be in Settings window.

P.S: There's only a menu item "Online Accounts" in main user menu which opens up settings window.

Comment: Any luck already? Facing same issue